# Algolia Shopify Instant Search on index.liquid

Tags: search, installation, shopify, algolia, instant

I recently installed the Algolia Shopify plugin. I was trying to bring the installed search page to a div on my homepage (index.liquid). Is there anyway to do this? It seems like instant search only works from the /search page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question probably fits more on Algolia's [discourse forum](https://discourse.algolia.com/c/shopify/) than StackOverflow.

This being said, I think you'll find your answer in [this FAQ](https://community.algolia.com/shopify/frequently-asked-questions.html#how-to-use-the-instant-search-on-other-pages) of the *Algolia for Shopify* community website:

> **How to use the instant search on other pages**
>
> A front-end developer is required for this step.
>
> You'll first obviously want to disable the autocomplete in the Store Configuration tab.
>   Then the most important thing here is to have a CSS selector which matches on every page one single element.
>
> For the rest, a diff is sometimes better than a long speech.
>   `In assets/algolia_instant_search.js.liquid`:
>
> [Code diff]